# WebRTC - ScreenSharing in Android/iOS

Tags: android, webrtc, screensharing

I am trying to figure out a way to do a screen share using webRTC. I was able to achieve the same in desktop using the API navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(). However, getDisplayMedia() is not functioning in an android device. The webRTC documentation hints that getDisplayMedia() isn't supported in Android/iOS [the last time I checked]. If that is the case then what is the alternative to getDisplayMedia() to achieve screen sharing when it comes to android/iOS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find anything?